# Css grid-template-columns minmax going smaller than the stated max?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
grid-auto-rows: 80px;
column-gap: 5px;
row-gap: 5px;
grid-auto-flow: dense;
```

I have the above code to create a responsive grid.  The min size for the columns should be 80px.  I'm filling the grid with div's to visualize it.  They're the following code.

```
grid-row: span 4;
grid-column: span 4;
background-color: green;
```

```
grid-row: span 2;
grid-column: span 2;
background-color: red;
```

```
grid-row: span 8;
grid-column: span 2;
background-color: blue;
```

It works fine full screen and is responsive for the most part, however when I resize the window to mobile there's an extra small column that gets produced.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K1eI.jpg

Inspector pictures in the above link.  The green blocks should be twice the size of the red blocks, which I think they are but they're being cut off.  You can also see the grid outlines show a very small column at the very end.  Why is this happening, I thought grid would just place the green block on a new row.

Edit: I believe the column-gap and row-gap was the cause and have deleted it.  Not sure how I would keep column-gap and row-gap in without the unexpected columns going under the stated minmax.

Comment: The small col is the green one on the right?

Comment: Does [the result](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GBC3FTKAYC83) as your expected?

Comment: @Nelles Yeah correct, it shows up correctly when full screened but not when scrunched to mobile.  https://imgur.com/a/5NIJ9h1 . <-- how it's supposed to look.

Comment: @Chunbin Li sorry, I'm not having trouble with the row length but the number and sizes of columns.  https://imgur.com/a/5NIJ9h1 The green boxes should look like that, or rather they should move to the next available spot in the grid down because of grid-auto-flow: dense; but it just squishes down into a tiny column.

Comment: Can you post a example with css and html?

Comment: @Chunbin Li Here's a link to a video with a timestamp at 11:28 https://youtu.be/qNtJ5p3h2A4?t=688 What I basically want is that except instead of images they're just colored empty divs.  https://github.com/ATung01/personal-hook is the project currently.  App.css is empty because I'm using styled-components to add the css to each component.  Everything is in Maingrid.js, I just manually added a bunch of shapes to test.

Comment: thanks for your description, would you create a raw html and css without react framework? I think it can let peoples easily to help you even they don't know how to use react.

Comment: Dose [the result](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-wzzas3) as  your expected

Comment: @Chunbin Li Hey I really appreciate all the help so far, I just wanted to say thanks to start :) Unfortunately it's still not what I'm looking for.  I'm trying to make sure the minimum size of each column is at least 80px (arbitrary value), your changes to grid-template-columns to only 1fr make the column squeeze down. I did find that I got expected behavior once I got rid of column-gap and row-gap!  So I'll be doing that instead.  Thanks again for the help though.

Comment: You can change grid-template-columns: `repeat(8, 1fr);` to `repeat(8, minmax(80px,1fr))`;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the min size to every child column that have set the custom size, you can use `calculated column total number` instead of `auto-fit` on the parent's `grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));`.

`grid-template-columns: repeat(8, minmax(80px,1fr));`

How to get calculated result of 8fr?

> red's grid-column : span 2
>
> blue's grid-column : span 2
>
> green's grid-column : span 4
>
> grid-column in one row = 8 (2(red) + 2(blue) + 4(green))

```
grid-column: span 2;
background-color: red;

grid-column: span 2;
background-color: blue;

grid-column: span 4;
background-color: green;
```